# Random order of the 5 most popular posts

Tags: posts, wp-query, order

I have a loop that shows the most popular posts with the `meta_value_num`.
I'm trying to randomize the order of the most 5 popular items.
Any idea why this code isn't working?

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=4&cat=-20,-54&orderby=meta_value_num&order=rand&meta_key=post_views_count&order=DESC'); ?>

<? if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        echo('<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' .ShortenText(get_the_title()). '<br></a>');
        $content = get_the_content();
        preg_match('#(<img.*?>)#', $content, $results);
        echo('<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . $results[1] . '</br></a>');
        ?></br><?
    endwhile;
endif;; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `order` parameter incorrectly for [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

> - order (string | array) - Designates the ascending or descending order of the 'orderby' parameter. Defaults to 'DESC'. An array can be used for multiple order/orderby sets.
>
>   - 'ASC' - ascending order from lowest to highest values (1, 2, 3; a, b, c).
>   - 'DESC' - descending order from highest to lowest values (3, 2, 1; c, b, a).

[`query_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) looks to be modifying the main query. In that case, remove `'rand'` from your query args and shuffle the posts directly afterwards.

```
query_posts('showposts=4&cat=-20,-54&orderby=meta_value_num&meta_key=post_views_count&order=DESC');

global $posts;
shuffle($posts);

if (have_posts()) :
    //...
endif;
```